# How to bind array data to SqlCommand.Parameter?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sqlcommand

It's possible to perform this operation without "foreach" ???

I would understand if there are library functions to associate a parameter a list of data and perform N insert all together

```
 String SQL_DETAIL = "INSERT INTO [ImportDetail] " +
                                                      " ([idMaster] " +
                                                      " ,[operation] " +
                                                      " ,[data]) " +
                                                 " VALUES " +
                                                      " (@a,@b,@c) ";

foreach (ImportDetail imp in this.lstImportDetail )
{

     SqlCommand dettCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL_DETAIL, myTrans.Connection);
     dettCommand.Transaction = myTrans;

     dettCommand.Parameters.Add("a", SqlDbType.Int).Value = imp.IdMaster;
     dettCommand.Parameters.Add("b", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = imp.Operation;
     dettCommand.Parameters.Add("c", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = imp.Data;


     i =i+ (int)dettCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

Thank for help

Comment: Yes. You can use `for` or `while`.

Comment: what's in the lstImportDetail ?

Comment: 1) Is there any special reason not to use `foreach`? 2) You need to use `@a`, `@b` and `@c` in your `.Add` method either. 3) With `foreach`, you need to `.Clear` all parameters beginning on each iteration. 4) You don't need to cast `int` since `ExecuteNonQuery` already returns `int`. 5) Use _using_ statement to dispose your database connections and objects.

Comment: It's a fragment of long transaction, anyway hand me a link to correct this. @SonerGönül

Comment: I would understand if there are library functions to associate a parameter a list of data and perform N insert all together @SonerGönül

Answer (score 1):

If you were feeling frisky, you could create a user-defined table type and put the data from all your `ImportDetail` objects into a `DataTable`. This wouldn't totally alleviate the need for a loop, though -- it just makes it more efficient since you're only transforming data in memory instead of passing it to a remote database. Once you have your `DataTable` populated to match the schema of your table type, you can pass it as a parameter to a stored procedure to handle your `INSERT`s. The procedure can be made transactional if you'd like, and since your input data will already be in a table (of sorts), the SQL for the stored procedure should be pretty simple, as well.

For more info on user-defined table types and how they're used in .NET, check out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx

Going a little further, if this is something you have to do quite often, it's not out of the realm of possibility to turn this into some sort of extension method on `IEnumerable` to keep things DRY.

Is this the sort of solution you were looking for? It's a little hard for me to tell given the wording of the question.

Comment: This is not what I was looking for but but thanks for the idea

Answer (score 1):

You can define two array list:
the first will have the name of the parameter and the second its value:

```
        ArrayList arrayName = new ArrayList { };
        ArrayList arrayValue = new ArrayList { };

        arrayName.Add("@Parameter1");
        arrayName.Add("@Parameter2");
        arrayValue.Add(value1);
        arrayValue.Add(value2);

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayName.Count; i++)
        {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(arrayName[i].ToString(), arrayValue[i]);
        }
```

Then execute command